# Unable to push message in rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am using node amqlib library to push message to rabbitmq, but not able to see any message in rabbitmq queue.Below mentioned is the code.Please suggest

```
 let amqp = require('amqplib')
  , configConnection = {
      protocol: 'amqp',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: 5672,
      username: '******',
      password: '************',
      locale: 'en_US',
      frameMax: 0,
      heartbeat: 0,
      vhost: '******',
   }
  , queue = '**********'
  , exchange = '******'
  , type = 'fanout'
  , read_message = 500
  ;
(async function() {
        try {
                let connection = await amqp.connect(configConnection);
                let channel = await connection.createChannel();
                await channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'fanout', {durable: true});
                let queue_details = await channel.assertQueue(queue);
                await channel.bindQueue(queue, exchange);
                msg = {"name":"xxxxx","mobile":"xxxxx"};
                msg_str = JSON.stringify(msg);
                let err, ok = await channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(msg_str));
                channel.close();
                connection.close();
        }
        catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
        }
})();
```

Comment: Are you looking into the right Vhost on your RabbitMQ interface ?